# rails-3, new comment form from a polymorphic association, accepts form submission but doesn't display submited data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic comment model and on the show.html.erb for the posts_controller,i have a link 'add comments', where you can click to comment on a post. When you click the link, the 'new comment form' comes up but when you submit the form, the comment doesn't display or show up anywhere in the app.Here is the gist with some view files and controllers: https://gist.github.com/828400 and here is the model, schema.rb and log file: https://gist.github.com/828447, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at **app/views/comments/_form.html.erb** you'll notice that it
builds a form using

```
[@post, Comment.new]
```

This means that it works correctly when you create a comment directly from a PostsController
view as **@post** is set correctly. This means that the form
builder sets the form's action to **/posts/5/comments** (where the 5 is
taken from @post.id), thus setting the post_id param which the CommentsController
looks for in CommentsController#get_parent.

However, when you click on 'Add a comment' or 'Add a reply' you are in
the CommentsController, which sets a variable called @parent. That
means that the form builder sets the form's action to **/comments**
(since @post is nil), which means when you submit the form both the post_id and
comment_id params are nil.

What this means that it reaches this line in CommentsController#get_parent:

```
redirect_to root_path unless defined?(@parent)
```

which means that your form contents are silently discarded.

The easiest way to get the forms to work correctly is to make the
following changes:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:

def show
-    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
+    @parent = @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

#app/views/comments/_form.html.erb b/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

-  
+
```

As you'll see, it means that the form looks for the @parent object
(instead of @post), which then gets set by PostsController & CommentsController.

As an aside, you could consider making the following changes to tighten up your code:

```
-  redirect_to root_path unless defined?(@parent)
+  redirect_to root_path unless @parent
```

If @parent is not defined it will return nil, which is considered false.

```
-  return @post if defined?(@post)
-  @post = commentable.is_a?(Post) ? commentable : commentable.post
+  @post ||= commentable.is_a?(Post) ? commentable : commentable.post
```

Also, you call Comment.new in your views. Generally, initializing object should be done in a controller, and views should be limited to presentation logic.

Comment: Thanks Luke, this worked like charm. Thanks for the detailed explanation too.